# Why are there fewer brown dwarfs than stars?

Tags: astronomy, brown-dwarfs

Lighter stars are more common than heavier stars, you'd think that this would make brown dwarfs more common than red dwarfs and yet they are less common by factors of a few.
(e.g. see Table 5 of [Scholz et al. 2012](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/744/1/6); see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149721/43351 ), why is this?

Comment: I'd imagine it has something to do with brown dwarf stars being harder to observe but maybe I am too unfamiliar with how they are spotted in the first place. Certainly more luminous stars are the easier to see.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ such that it _cites your sources_.  Give a _book or article citation_ or _link to a web page_.  _Who_ is saying that brown dwarfs are less common than red dwarfs, and do they give any reason?

Comment: This is a research-level question without a definitive answer. (BTW iit is certainly true that red dwarfs outnumber brown dwarfs by factors of a few).

Comment: The linked paper is an observational census. Is it possible that the small number of brown dwarfs is due (at least partially) to observation bias (they're faint)?

Comment: That wouldn’t follow for searches sufficiently close.